# List of authors with AND included

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have a custom .bst file and .sty file. I want my bibliography output as ' if the number of authors greater than two, put an and in front of the final author of that list'. I can't find out the code to be modified in my custom .bib file or in .sty file. Kindly do the needful.

my code is

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{f{.}.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              "," *
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                { " " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
```

Comment: that would be the usual behaviour but without seeing your existing code how can anyone suggest how to change it? look at `FUNCTION {format.names}` for example in the `plain.bst` that comes with bibtex.

Comment: code is included in the question

Comment: As usual show us a short compilable tex code building your bibliography,your used bib entry and tell us where we can download the modified bst file ...